# Is it possible to simplify O(n! + n)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I was reading about time complexity and came across time complexity O(n! + n). Is it possible to simplify this? If so, how would you do it?

Comment: This is hardly stackoverflow question.  You can read about complexity in any algorithm book. Try skiena introduction to...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about mathematics. Try Math.SE.

Answer (score 4):

As hints, for n ≥ 2, notice that

> n! + n ≤ n! + n! = 2n!

and that

> n! + n > n!

Can you use these observations to find a simpler way of expressing O(n! + n)?

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Even @templatetypedef 's answer is correct and try to help you to take the solution in that specific case, we can try to give to you more tools to use it in practice.

Straight from [big O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) definition you can say:

1. `O(f(n)+g(n)) = O(f(n)) + O(g(n))`
2. `O(k f(n)) = k O(f(n)) = O(f(n))`
3. if `f(n)` is a `O(n)` then `f(n)` is a `O(n!)`

Where 1 and 2 came directly from limsup properties and 3 is a simple exercise. By these 3 sentences we can say:

> O(n! + n) = O(n!) + O(n) = 2 O(n!) = O(n!)